# rails 4 trying to implement follow / unfollow features between users, but error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, relationship

I'm trying to implement follow/unfollow features to my application among users. I am using devise + omniauth and using a separate users controller. When I click on follow button, it does not do anything with the numbers that is supposed to count the following / followers,etc. in the console i get these errors

```
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ReTtZn0GbB7f5LROr6FLnw40ErDDcubDa8/yLnyVd/FIhxM3qjZI8pjYDAGmuGJiv1paGVjhp/LMVmFtkcZVwQ==", "followed_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Follow"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Relationship: followed_id
        app/models/user.rb:21:in `follow'
        app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:7:in `create'
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  Relationship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = ? AND "relationships"."followed_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["follower_id", 2], ["followed_id", 1]]
  Rendered users/_unfollow.html.erb (11.5ms)
  Rendered relationships/create.js.erb (13.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms

ArgumentError (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
  app/views/users/_unfollow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__unfollow_html_erb___2456782614560778317_70319555077280'
  app/views/relationships/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_create_js_erb__3841758023410302021_45366420'
  app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

My lines of code are as follows

relationship_controller

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

_follow_form.html.erb

```
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

_unfollow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

create / destroy .js.html

```
$("#follow_form").html('<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>')
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')

$("#follow_form").html('<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>')
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

**Thank you in advance.. I am dying to figure this out...**

EDITED My error trackbacks

Comment: In Rails 4 you have to whitelist params. Use the following: def private_params params[:yourmodel] permit(:yourkeys, :anotherkey] end

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the form submitted was empty/nil.

This is due to not accepting the form and its attributes.

Add this to your controller

```
private
    def private_params
        params[:yourmodel].permit(:yourkeys, :anotherkey]
end
```

Comment: I added private def private_params
          params[:relationship].permit(:follower_id, :followed_id)
        end but still getting the same error.. any other suggestion? thanks for your initial input

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem through removing protected_attributes gem in my old gem. It is a remnant of the rails 3 and clashes with the new rails 4. So, if anyone is having issues. Please remove this gem and be aware that rails 4 is using strong parameters now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same error as you, I can't recall exactly.

For me, **everything was working great**, the follow/unfollow feature was working but when I unfollowed a user I was always getting this kind of error.

The solution for me was to change the unfollow `form_for` to a `link_to` :

```
<%= link_to current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id), remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Unfollow</button>
<% end %>
```

And the error disappeared.

Take a look at this [simple & quick tutorial](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails) for more infos.